# Quick Unix command to print non-contiguous lines from a text file?

Tags: shell, unix, text, sed

Given a text file named "people.txt" which consists of:

```
Anne
Bob
Carl
Daphne
Erwin
Gary
Heather
```

How can I use a sed command or similar one-liner which specifies only a set of non-consecutive line numbers in order to filter the contents to this result:

```
Bob
Erwin
Heather
```

(Note: ignore the fact that they are alphabetical)

Note that the real file I am using has over 100K lines, so the answer should consider efficiency.

I know I can use:

```
sed '5q;d' people.txt
```

to get *only* line 5 ("Erwin"), but is there a variation on this argument in which I can specify a list of arbitrary line numbers?

I think this is possible with sed alone, but even after reading through man sed I am having trouble figuring this out. I've been looking at other answers that come very close to doing this but nearly all of them deal with getting either just a single line or contiguous lines (a range of lines), or that use a more complicated bash script; for instance, ["Quick unix command to display specific lines in the middle of a file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191364/quick-unix-command-to-display-specific-lines-in-the-middle-of-a-file) and ["How can I print specific lines from a file in Unix?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319517/how-can-i-print-specific-lines-from-a-file-in-unix).

Comment: What do you mean by **non-consecutive line numbers**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ask for specific lines *by number* like this:

```
sed -n '1p;5p;7p' my_file
```

The `-n` flag means, "don't print lines by default", and then for each line you want, you specify the line number and the `p` (print) command.

Comment: Ah, that is probably what the OP wanted. Couldn't descipher it before I saw your answer :-)

Comment: Great, thank you! I figured it was something simple like that. I will test this out today, but perhaps you know off-hand: will this work well if I am picking out 50K lines from a 200K-line file?

Comment: Good answer - especially as it includes explanation of what's going on. Some `sed` features can be a little inscrutable :).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v lines="2 4 7" 'index(" "lines" "," "NR" ")' file  
Bob
Daphne
Heather

$ awk -v lines="3 5" 'index(" "lines" "," "NR" ")' file  
Carl
Erwin
```

The blank chars around `lines` and `NR` in the above are necessary so that `NR` value `9` doesn't match when `lines` contains `19`, for example.

If you don't mind hard-coding the line numbers inside the script you could alternatively do:

```
awk 'NR~/^(2|4|7)$/' file
```

Comment: @AdamKatz - the edit you made yesterday to remove the blank chars around the index() args broke the script in the above answer and I had to change it back just now. Please don't edit my awk answers as I generally know what I'm doing. Please do feel free to leave me a comment if you think an answer I posted is wrong and I'll be happy to explain or fix it..

Comment: interesting (and my apologies on that). It worked for me when I tested it.  Can you explain why those quotes are necessary?  All they do is concatenate spaces onto both ends of your lines.

Comment: No problem. You need to always have blanks around NR to avoid false matches (NR=`9` falsely matches the 19 in lines=`3<blank>19<blank>7`, but NR=`<blank>9<blank>` does not) and since you need blanks around NR, you need to make sure there's always a blank at the start and end of lines too (NR=`<blank>3<blank>` undesirably does not match lines=`3<blank>19<blank>7`, but does match lines=`<blank>3<blank>19<blank>7<blank>`). Code that produces the expected output from a given input set is always trivial to write, it's code that won't produce unexpected output for other inputs that gets complicated.

Comment: ah.  Then why not do `awk -v lines=" 2 4 7 " 'index(lines, " " NR " ")' file`?  Also, I'm still getting just 2,4,7 from `seq 1 999 |awk -v lines='2 4 7' 'index(lines,NR)'` using mawk 1.3.3 or gawk 4.1.1.

Comment: It's better to not rely on the user of the script to pad with blanks when you can add them inside the script. In general `lines` will not be hard-coded - if it was you wouldn't need it at all you could just hard-code the first arg to index(). The failure occurs when you have 2-digit (or more) numbers inside `lines` (e.g. 19) ,because then a single-digit NR e.g. (1 or 9) will match on either of the digits. Try `awk -v lines="19" 'index(lines,NR)' file` on a file with 20 lines, then `awk -v lines="19" 'index(lines," "NR" ")' file` and then `awk -v lines="19" 'index(" "lines" "," "NR" ")' file`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I hadn't realized that `index()` was a substring function.  I might suggest something more like `awk 'NR == 2 || NR == 4 || NR == 7' file` in that case, as it's more straightforward, but using `index()` is certainly quite clever.

Comment: `awk 'NR == 2 || NR == 4 || NR == 7' file` would be fine to check for 3 hard-coded line numbers but if that was what was wanted I'd use `NR~/^(2|4|7)$/` (which I just added to my answer) as the former isn't a good general solution as it's around 90% redundant code and it doesn't do what the OP requested which for a `one-liner which specifies only a set of non-consecutive line numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generate the sed program:

store the lines you want in an array:

```
$ lines=(2 5 7)
$ sed -n "$(printf "%dp;" "${lines[@]}")" file
Bob
Erwin
Heather
```

or if the line numbers are in a file:

```
$ sed -n "$(sed 's/$/p/' numbers)" file
```